# Oracle update existing record or insert new

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table defined like this:

```
CIC3.WBCOURSEACTIVITY
(
  WCA_RID           NUMBER,
  WCA_TNA_ID        NUMBER,
  WCA_REG_RID       NUMBER,
  WCA_ANSWERED_PTS  NUMBER,
  WCA_TOTAL_PTS     NUMBER,
  WCA_TITLE         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
)
```

I want to update any record where I send the same WCA_TNA_RID and WCA_REG_RID combination that already exists otherwise, I want to insert a new record. I have a sequence on WCA_RID

Does this look like it'll do the trick or can it be better?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CIC3.f_savewbpoints(pParticipantID number, pRegRid number, pAnsweredPoints number, pTotalPoints number, pTitle VARCHAR2) is
    vWcaRid number;
begin    
    SELECT DISTINCT wca_rid INTO vWcaRid 
    FROM wbcourseactivity 
    WHERE wca_reg_rid = pRegRid 
      AND wca_tna_id = pParticipantID;

    UPDATE wbcourseactivity 
    SET wca_answered_pts = pAnsweredPoints
      , wca_totalPts = pTotalPoints
      , wca_title = pTitle
    WHERE wca_rid = vWcaRid
    IF (NVL(SQL%ROWCOUNT, 0) = 0) THEN 
            INSERT INTO wbcourseactivity (wca_tna_id
                                        , wca_reg_rid
                                        , wca_answered_pts
                                        , wca_total_pts
                                        , wca_title) 
            VALUES 
                                         (pParticipantID
                                        , pRegRid
                                        , pAnsweredPoints
                                        , pTotalPoints
                                        , pTitle);
    END IF; 
    commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: btw `IF (NVL(SQL%ROWCOUNT, 0) = 0)` can be simplified to `if sql%rowcount = 0`. It can't be null following a SQL statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`MERGE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CIC3.f_savewbpoints(pParticipantID number, pRegRid number, pAnsweredPoints number, pTotalPoints number, pTitle VARCHAR2) is
begin
    merge into wbcourseactivity a
    using (
        SELECT DISTINCT wca_rid, wca_reg_rid, wca_tna_id
        FROM wbcourseactivity 
        WHERE wca_reg_rid = pRegRid 
        AND wca_tna_id = pParticipantID;
    ) b on (
        a.wca_rid = b.wca_rid
        and a.wca_reg_rid = b.wca_reg_rid
        and a.wca_tna_id = b.wca_tna_id
    )
    when matched then update set a.wca_answered_pts = pAnsweredPoints
    when not matched then insert (wca_tna_id, wca_reg_rid, wca_answered_pts, wca_total_pts, wca_title)
                        values (pParticipantID, pRegRid, pAnsweredPoints, pTotalPoints, pTitle);
    commit;
end;
/
```

Comment: Tried it, it didn't work. The function I wrote works just great with a few tweaks. If you don't mind, I'll give you the points anyway.